# Which process is using GPU?

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card

I bought an MSI GTX960, and I would like to know which application (process) is currently using it.

I remember back in the days when I had a laptop with an nVidia `GT555m`, I had this small nVidia tray application (it was installed with the driver), that shows the icons of the applications that are currently using the GPU, but I cannot seem to find it.

Can anyone suggest a way I can determine which processes are using my GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) can be configured to monitor GPU usage in several different ways.

From the process list (View -> Select Columns):

[image: Proces GPU Usage]

From the System Information graphs (View -> System Information):

[image: GPU Graph]

Or from Process Explorer's tray icon (I currently monitor CPU, RAM & GPU usage):

[image: Tray Graphs]

Comment: How can I see multiple GPUs here? I have the integrated Intel HD GPU and an AMD Radeon, but Process Explorer shows me only one (I don't know which. Probably Intel)